# React event propagating in the else case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

let's say I have a function that gets executed on key press that looks like something like this. I want to have special case for when Enter is pressed otherwise I want even to propogate/bubble up to the browser. Therefore, if any other key is pressed this i.e up or down arrows they should work.

```
 onAutosuggestInputKeyDown = event => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
     this.onCustomSuggestionCreate(event)
  } else {
      // keep propgating the event 
  }
}


getAutosuggestInputProps = () => {
    return {
      inputProps: {
        onBlur: this.onCustomSuggestionCreate,
        onKeyDown: this.onAutosuggestInputKeyDown,
      },
    }
  }


<ReactAutoSuggest textFieldProps={this.getAutosuggestInputProps()}/>
```

Comment: Event bubbling is default behaviour. You can stop the bubbling by doing `stopPropagation`. I can't understand what you're expecting in the `else` block. Can you provide a reproducible working example of the problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, then even propagation should occour by default (depending on the type of element that fired the event).

You would however, likely want to use [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the case of the enter key being pressed to prevent the propagation of that event, which would be achieved by the following update to your `onAutosuggestInputKeyDown` method:

```
onAutosuggestInputKeyDown = event => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {

     // Prevent this event from propagating if enter key pressed
     event.stopPropagation()

     this.onCustomSuggestionCreate(event)
  }

  // If stopPropagation() not called on event, the event will propagate
  // if it has the ability to do so (ie from the element dispatching the 
  // event)
}
```

Comment: but it does not propgate it, I want to forcefully propgate it

Comment: what is your event coming from? a text `<input />`? 
where do you want it to propagate to?